# Maven Profile concept in a NodeJS Project without MVN

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, production, maven-profiles

Hello stakOverFlowers :D 
I have a simple NodeJS WebApp that use Lerna to manage the project. So i have a package directory that contains n different projects each ones using different tasks runner tools.

I always use Maven Build Profile in java environment but for this NodeJS project maven will not be used.
So the question is... 
Is there a way to reproduce the Maven Build Profile concept without using MVN? 

In a nutshell i need to use a build profile in nodejs, without using MVN, to customize build for different environments such as Production v/s Development environments.

There's a way to do that? 
thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, following the TGW advice, works!!
Just install the config module, and create a directory that containing .json files.

`$ npm install config
 $ mkdir config
 $ vi config/default.json`

Than if u are on a windows machine, choose your NODE_ENV using `NODE_ENV=production` and than execute your web app.
In your .js file put informations like yours dbConnection host and password.... and to retrieve it use:

`var config = require('config');
 var dbConfig = config.get('JsonItem.dbConfig');`

..more details on https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by storing your configurations in a JSON file as key value pairs in the same way as you do in properties file in Java.
Then by someway or other invoke properties from the environment specific configuration file such as production.json or stage.json or qa.json.

One of the easy ways to do this is using this module named [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)

Using this you can pass NODE_ENV=production(or dev or qa whatever) and access relevant configurations. This will help you achieve environment profiling.

You can also store configurations in a JS file but I personally prefer a JSON file for storing configurations.

But if you're wondering for dependencies management that is done by package.json file which is somewhat similar to your pom.xml file. 
For more details about it you might want to read [this official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for it.

Comment: do u think there is not plugin that do this job? thx for your suggestion.

Comment: I am not aware about such plugin, there might be some but I never felt a need to look into that option.